# Should the high frequency filter be implemented in the differential signal or is afterward ok?

Tags: emi-filtering

1. Should a high frequency filter be implemented on the differential signals input like in the following [Olimex EMG/EKG](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Duino/Shields/SHIELD-EKG-EMG/open-source-hardware) amplifier, or can it be implemented after the Vinput+ and Vinput- have passed through a unity amplifier and single ended output Vout? what would the HF filter look like if implemented after it?
2. Is the high frequency filter the same as RFI filter? Do both filter EMI from air and from line? Then how do EMI/RFI filter from air and line differ?

From the [SHIELD-EKG-EMG schematic](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Duino/Shields/SHIELD-EKG-EMG/resources/SHIELD-EKG-EMG-REV-B-SCHEMATIC.pdf):

[image]

Comment: Maybe the data sheet of the so-called "instrumental" amplifier will illuminate. BTW it's called an instrumentation amplifier in that it is used for processing signals from instrumentation devices (and not amplifying guitar or keyboard solos). I'd also be concerned about what sources the signal V_REF.

Comment: this is datasheet of the olimex but my question is not about the olimex. its just an example..i was just asking if it is better to implement the high frequency or rfi filter at differential inputs or after any amplifier https://www.olimex.com/Products/Duino/Shields/SHIELD-EKG-EMG/resources/SHIELD-EKG-EMG.pdf

Comment: It's not as clear cut as "is it better" (one way or the other). It depends on the signals (both differential and common mode) and how much you want to spend on CM capacitors.

Comment: I want to see examples where the rfi filter is implemented after the amplifier. i was thinking and read others say it should always be implemented right after the input

Answer (score 3):

> *Should a high frequency filter be implemented on the differential
> signals input like in the following Olimex EMG/EKG amplifier*

Sometimes, it's a really bad idea to implement CM filter capacitors as shown here (C2 and C3): -

[image]

The reason is because they have a value tolerance and, if that tolerance means that one is 5% high and, the other is 5% low, you will get CM signals (normally ignored when the capacitors are unfitted) being converted to differential signals. You can't do anything about differential signals; they are what you want to amplify but now, with the C2 and C3 capacitors, any significant CM signal is going to muck-up your wanted differential signal.

So, I don't favour them unless the likely CM signals are spectrally miles-away from the wanted spectrum of the differential signal you want to process. Quite often this is the case i.e. you are wanting to process an audio like signal and the CM interference is above (say) 1 MHz. This would be likely called an **RFI filter** and, if that is what is intended with C2 and C3 then, they are in the right place.

> *can it be implemented after the Vinput+ and Vinput- have passed
> through a unity amplifier and single ended output Vout? what would the
> HF filter look like if implemented after it?*

Just a regular RC low-pass filter is good enough but, quite often higher order filters are used like the Sallen-Key filters shown in your diagram.

Comment: I thought high frequency filter is the same as RFI filter. they are not the same? what is the difference?

Comment: @Jtl if I interpret what you ask correctly, C1 is a differential filter and C2/C3 form a common-mode (CM) filter and, both can be regarded as RFI filters. A HF filter is very likely an RFI filter also. However, neither are very well defined definitions.

Comment: So maybe the rule is not to implement HF/RFI filters right after amplifiers with any gain because the HF/RFI can be amplified too and it's not good for the signal. So the only time filters can be used after the amplifier if it is a unity (gain 1) buffer amplifier only?

Comment: @Jtl a unity (or low gain) front-end amplifier is a good choice. Anything with significant gain could hit output saturation at the intermediate stages within an instrumentation amplifier. When that happens it is usually unresolvable without lowering front-end gain.

Comment: If common mode provokes nonlinear behavior in the amp, you'll want to filter it out.

Comment: If you know how other bioamplifiers implement their RFI/HF filters, please share any because my question is not the olimex in particular (it is just an example). I want to see if other bioamplifiers have to use unity amplifiers just for purpose of putting the filter after the amplifier Vout or they directly put it right at the differential inputs. I want to know the pro and con of each that's why I was asking it in the original question.

Comment: @Jtl without hours of research into other possible systems, I don't see how this can be addressed. However, I do think that a bioamplifier is a good corner case.

Comment: A bioamplifier will have considerable levels of CM (unwanted signal) and almost within the spectrum of the wanted signal i.e. 50/60 Hz from AC power cables. For this reason, the CM interference is definitely not RF and, it's likely that C2 and C3 could cause an excessive error without proper care.

Comment: If you wont use C2 and C3. what other ways to filter HF/RFI in the differential signal? Remember the olimex thing is just example. The purpose I asked the question is to add filter to a unit without any existing filters.

Comment: @Jtl I never said I wouldn't use C2 and C3 so, re-ask your question with that corrected please and, take note that if the signal you want to measure is much lower in the spectrum than RF interference then, it's perfectly OK to use an RFI filter. Just make sure it doesn't imbalance CM signals that you want to reject that are close to your desired spectrum (such as 50/60 Hz).

Comment: Ok You will still use C2 and C3. But is it not the purpose of the amp with CMRR is to reject common mode signals. What happens if you don't put C2 and C3. Won't any common mode signal be removed by the amp?

Comment: CM signals will be removed by the amplifier but,  if they are too high in frequency (above the working limit of the amp) it could become messy.

Comment: @Andyaka I I read the values right, the CM filter caps are only 100 pF, while the DM cap is 100 times larger. So, the DM cap is going to strongly attenuate any CM->DM coupling here.

Comment: Repeatedly, the OP has stated that the circuit is just an example so, I have tried to be as general as possible. However, those small caps are for RFI and won't really do much at the desired spectrum but, given that this type of application suffers from very high common mode interference at 50/60 Hz, one has to be careful with these small capacitors.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of the input filter in a low frequency measurement device like this is to keep EMI from driving the input amplifier into nonlinear behavior. So, you can't move it to the output. This circuit *has* filters on the output of the differential stage. The "regulated gain" stage is configured as a low-pass filter, and it feeds a "Butterworth filter" stage.

Comment: If the amplifier is unity with gain of 1. can it contribute to the non linear behavior? what will be the advantage or disadvantage if using HF/RFI filter on the single ended output Vout of the unity amplifier versus directly filtering it in the differential input before the common mode signals were removed by the unity amplifier?

Comment: @jtl A unity gain amplifier may behave nonlinearly to input signals outside its bandwidth. A filter on its output will not affect this behavior.